# Add Extra parameter with url in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

i am new in asp.net mvc3. i want to add extra parameter with url before controller like:-

```
Newparameter/{controller}/{action}/{id};
```

is it posible and also i need to change its value.

Please Help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible, just add a new route in your Global.asax like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default with new param", // Route name
            "{newParameter}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Place this before the default route as it's more specific.

Then create an action method that takes 'newParameter' as a method parameter

Answer (score 1):

you will have to define a new route in `Global.ascx` like

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "RouteName",
              "{Param}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }             

            );
```

and dont forget to place your new route above the default route